# If f is a scalar field and f is a vector field , which one of the following expressions does not make sense?

Tags: vector-fields, scalar-fields

If f is a scalar field and **f** is a vector field , which one of the following expressions does not make sense?

1)▽×**f** = (2x,3yz,-xz^2)

2)▽(▽•**f**)

3)(▽×**f**)×(▽f)

4)▽•(▽f)

Comment: the first I suppose

Comment: Don't use the same letter for two different things.

Comment: could you please consider accepting the answer ?

Answer (score 1):

The first is not because if you take the divergence then it is naot zero. Indeed
$$
\nabla \cdot (\nabla \times \mathbf f) = \nabla \cdot (2x,3yz,-xz^2)^T = 2+3z-2xz \ne 0
$$
I assume you know that $\nabla \cdot \nabla \times= 0$